# ML350 Using both p800 and e200i

Tags: raid, storage, hp, hp-proliant, hp-smart-array

I have an ML350 G5 with a P800 and the integrated e200i. I'm using the P800 to service the main drive cage with 6 SAS drives in RAID 5. However, I would love to also convert some of the unused 5.25" bays into more internal storage(with some 5.25 to 3.5" cage caddy things)

My questions are:

1: Is it possible to use the P800 and the E200i at once?

2: If so, would I need another backplane of some kind, or can I plug the 2 inputs to the E200i straight into a pair of large(2 or 3 TB) SATA drives?

3: Finally, I read on similar thread on this very site that, running this set up, it would be preferable to not share the i/o bus between the e200i and the p800; How can I tell which bus each card is on?

Thanks!

Ultra-finally and mostly off topic: I bought this server on the cheap, and the seller said it had an issue where it would shut off randomly with an unpredictable period ranging from 1 day to 2 weeks. Any idea what this could be? I haven't observed it yet because I haven't been running the server for more than a few hours at a time yet. I'm really hoping it was a software issue because I just reimaged it with Debian(they had windows server 2003) If it is hardware, what could it be?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use multiple Smart Array controllers at the same time. You should be able to see the system board connectors for the Smart Array E200i. You will need breakout cables to accommodate any bare SAS or SATA drives you mount in the 5.25" bays. You'll also need power for those drives.

Be sure to update the firmware of both controllers and the system before you go much farther. Download the [bootable HP Firmware DVD](http://h20566.www2.hp.com/portal/site/hpsc/template.PAGE/public/psi/swdDetails/?sp4ts.oid=4091432&spf_p.tpst=psiSwdMain&spf_p.prp_psiSwdMain=wsrp-navigationalState=lang%253Den%257Ccc%253DUS%257CprodSeriesId%253D4091412%257CprodNameId%253D4091432%257CswEnvOID%253D4103%257CswLang%253D8%257CswItem%253DMTX-9ed665a89aba447d925937f38b%257Caction%253DdriverDocument&javax.portlet.begCacheTok=com.vignette.cachetoken&javax.portlet.endCacheTok=com.vignette.cachetoken) to take care of this.

As for IRQ settings for the cards, you can access that via the BIOS page before POST.